# Problems getting Bitmap from Camera taken image onto ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I want to let the user set something of a contact icon, the user can either take a picture or choose one from the gallery. I have the following start activity for result, noting I handle the two differently here, but they should instead be handled the same:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.TAKE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                File file = new File(selectedImage.getPath());
                mPhoto = decodeFile(file);
                Bitmap croppedImage = cropImage(mPhoto);
                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(croppedImage, 100, 100, true);
                Bitmap finalPhoto = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 100);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(finalPhoto);
            }
            break;

        case Constants.CHOOSE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }
```

The second case, CHOOSE_PHOTO works. I choose a photo from the gallery, it gets placed in the ImageView. The thing is, the methods I've created in the first case, TAKE_PHOTO are kind of important, the Bitmap gets reshaped into a circle and cropped accordingly; for small sized pictures this worked exactly how I wanted it to. The main error was Out of Memory. I looked into it on SO and the found the following method to handle this:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

I thought that this would take Bitmap dimensions, record things before loading Bitmap into memory, then scale the Bitmap before loading it until OOM error was avoided entirely. However, when I ran the code the app still crashed upon trying to confirm a taken photo for selection, as if an OOM error had indeed occurred. I had the following Logcat at the time of the crash:

```
07-25 11:01:51.396  13054-13054/com.example.android.home E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.android.home/com.tabletnanny.ChildSelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3322)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3365)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1315)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tabletnanny.ChildSelection.onActivityResult(ChildSelection.java:126)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3318)
```

I've been looking into this for the greater part of a few hours and still can't seem to figure out how I can effectively load the Bitmap. I looked into the Android Dev site, where they had a useful tutorial on handling large Bitmaps, but their solution was very similar to the one I found on SO in the `decodeFile` method. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this for getting bitmap in ActivityForResult()

```
    Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

Comment: Actually if you don't mind my asking, how would I adapt this to the case where the user chooses a photo instead of taking one? This worked perfectly for taking a photo, but still resulted in a crash on account of the `Bitmap picture...` line in the case where I wanted to choose from gallery?

Comment: Note that this may not work on all devices. There has been a long discussion about the size, rotation and other issues (very common on Samsung devices) - see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1480